# How to make JQuery Loop to get different images

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am working to consume images using a REST call .
When I parse one Image , it's working out .

```
 var img = data.results[0].value; 
 $('#result').html("<img id='img1'>"); $('#img1').attr('src', img);
```

But when I did loop to get different images , it won't work .

```
$.each(data.items, function(i,item){
          var img = data.results[i].value; 

         htmlString += '<li><img src=' + img +'/></li>';
});
$('#result').html(htmlString);
```

Do I have problem with JQuery Loop !

Comment: this is not a loop. you always get same images because data.results[0].value;  try results[i]

Comment: You're setting `img` to `results[0]` no matter what, and for some reason using `data.items` instead of `data.results`

Comment: also, base on meaning of the literary, this make no sense. why loop items element, then set image from results elements?

Comment: I, all the time, try to get new image by looping , the first line is working out (no problem with the API ! )

Comment: what i mean if 'items' only has one element. this loop only runs once. no matter how many 'results' in  'data'

Comment: No ; I don't have just only one element 'check the i variable' - I tested it by getting one element to see if I am getting an answer from the REST Call . But when I tried to get many elements , it doesn't work out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to loop data.results, not data.items

see:[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/13/)

```
    success: function (data) {

           var $ul=$('<ul/>');

     $.each(data.results, function(i,item){ // on this line
        var img = item.value;  
         $ul.append($('<li/>').append($('<img/>').attr('src',img)   ));
      });

       $('#result').html($ul);

    }
```

Comment: What if I wanna add a title under every image . How can I do that !

Comment: that's ohter jquery thing. title tag could be .append() in $('<li/>') or $('<img/>').after() in your loop, it's up to you. if you want beautiful title, check third party library.

Comment: caoglish : Can you please check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922437/parsing-in-jquery