# Parsing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to parse what I am getting  JQuery to show data ! I am consuming data from an API , but I am getting an error .

Can I do a Loop on JQuery this way ?

```
$.each(data.results, function (i, item) { // on this line

    var Name = item.name;
    var Date = item.auditInfo.dateCreated;
    var Creator = item.creator.display;
    $htmlstring.append($('<li/>').append('<p>Test</p>'));
    $htmlstring.append("<div class='title'> Info : "
    Name + Date + Creator "</div>");

}); $('#afficher').html($htmlstring);
```

I am sharing code on JSFiddle (Check drug_omrsRestCall function ) :

http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/23/

Comment: Please give details of the error you're getting

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : can you please check demo ! I am sharing my code on JS Fiddle

Comment: The concept should work just fine, but you start off with $htmlstring being an UL element, and then you append DIV's, paragraphs and other crap as direct children of the UL, and that is bound to fail, as an UL can only have LI children. The fiddle doesn't work for me

Comment: The JSFiddle can't be tested because the REST URLs are relative. So, it'd be useful to know the error you are getting.

Comment: @DerickLeony : The problem is not with REST URl ; I have been debugging using Chrome Console (I can load objects ) . So, seems that the problem is with JQuery .

Comment: Nevertheless, if you expect someone to help you, you should do the best to assist them. At least, provide them with a JSON response. You can use `JSON.stringify()` to get a sample. I would also remove redundant code that is irrelevant to the question from the fiddle.

Comment: @MasterAM : True , I am trying to get some information using REST call , Just ignore last demo and check this one : http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/25/ , Use Google console to see drug object (drug object information ) , Now I am trying to parse it using JQuery http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/24/   , I am looping into all the objects , and trying to represent the different fields of every object ? Does this make sense ?

Comment: I am getting a `405 (Method Not Allowed)` error. You should probably create a fiddle with a static sample response.

Comment: Oops ! Check this one : http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/28/

Answer (score 0):

As @adeneo commented on the question, the concept is right but you should be careful about what element you are appending HTML content to.

With this snippet of your code:

```
$htmlstring.append("<div class='title'> Info : "
    Name + Date + Creator "</div>");
```

(BTW, it is missing two plus signs for a correct concatenation, I hope that's not the error you are getting).

you append a DIV to the UL and you actually want to append it to the LI, for example:

```
$('<li />').append("<p>Test</p>")
    .append("<div class='title'> Info : " + Name + Date + Creator + "</div>")
    .appendTo($htmlstring);
```

Check this fiddle for a working solution of your issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/d3dcj/2/

Comment: Thanks , Are you getting results when you run this demo  http://jsfiddle.net/d3dcj/ !

Comment: My bad, I might have not saved the changes. Please see this one: http://jsfiddle.net/d3dcj/2/

Comment: Oops ! That part of my code is working ! (I successfully can get information using the second function ) . The part I am asking about is not working ! Thanks . Check this demo ! I cleaned up the code  http://jsfiddle.net/zTXyq/24/